# Google + not allowing my game to start "unfortunately, Google+ couldn't set up your profile. Try again later"

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-games

I was trying to setup Google Play Leaderboards in my app, by following the instructions on googles website.

1. I created a Leaderboard for my app (not submitted yet).
2. Downloaded the "Android Basic Samples" code from Github, and copied the four source files "BaseGameActivity","BaseGameUtils","GameHelper","GameHelperUtils".
3. Updated my AndroidManifest.xml, strings.xml, ids.xml and build.gradle
4. In my app activity, I changed the class to extend BaseGameActivity.

On launching my app, my app immediately tries to sign into google play or something (it shows a Google Play Games Logo "connecting to"), and then shows a message

> "Create a profile. Unfortunately, Google+ couldn't set up your
>   profile. Try again later."

If I click on "Done", then Google Play Games prompts me to choose an account. So I click on my developer account (the other option being to create an account), and the same thing happens again (It shows the google now message)!

I've never created an Android App before, or used Google Play before, so all this is new to me. How should I fix this ?

EDIT: If I just click outside the "Google+" dialogue box, then it disappears and my game starts. Likewise in the loop if I press "cancel" when it asks me to choose an account, my game starts. But I can't test if leaderboards is working then! How do I fix this ? Why do I need a google+ profile ?

EDIT: And why is it having trouble setting one up ? Is there some setting I need to use to disable Google plus? I am using Android 4.4.4 and android-10, Google Play Services 7.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try logging in to your g+ profile before starting the game. The problem is not with your app, but with how the leader boards are authenticated. Hence why g+ is needed. : )

Edit: If the above fails, I would try to recreate another g+ profile. And if *that* fails, contact the play team at: https://support.google.com/googleplay#topic=3364260&contact=1

Best of luck!

Comment: You are correct, and apparently you cannot use non-gmail accounts with google play -> Your googleid may be something@someotheraddress.com, but you cannot have a google+ account unless it is like something@gmail.com. The message doesn't tell you this! Very user-unfriendly.

Comment: I agree. Worst part is, this happens to all users, effectively cornering them into making a g+ account, while putting the blame on the developer. Sneaky Google.